# How do I get windows to restore their position when (dis)connecting external monitor on laptop?

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, 22.04, display

I recently did a fresh install of Kubuntu 22.04 on my laptop and having troubles with my laptop and an external monitor. When I disconnect my external monitor, which is larger than the laptop, the windows are resized to fit. This is good.

When I reconnect the external monitor, the desktop expands to fill the space there, but the windows are not restored to their previous location. I have another laptop still running 18.04 where the windows do restore their position.

**How can I get my windows to go back to their previous location?**

I unify the outputs when the external display is connected, that is, I have the laptop display and external monitor display the same thing.

I'm using a Lenovo T14 if relevant.

Linux edaqa-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-3 5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 19:54:14 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

---

Probably unrelated, but for reference in case it is: when using unified outputs the laptop is not shrinking the display to fit, instead simply overflowing the desktop outside of the physical dimensions. 18.04 also didn't have this problem.

---

I'd be happy if I could simply get edge stickiness and vertical/horizontal maximize restored. Perhaps the problem lies here somehow, that the desktop is using absolute sizes now instead of these properties?

---

There might be even more at play here, as I often notice the maximize size of some of my windows is dictacted by the smaller monitor, not the large one. I don't think the "Unify Outputs" option is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try Wayland instead of X11.
I'm running Kubuntu and on the login screen I can choose Wayland or X11.  If I use Wayland and have the desktop set to 'restore last session' then my windows are restored when plugging/unplugging an external display.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain I am using Wayland, as I think it's the default. But I'll double check.